# Scheduling algorithm storage

Tags: java, priority-queue

I need some help on figuring out a way to store my data that is efficient. I am writing a scheduling algorithm using priority queues which include not-yet-submitted, ready, running, blocked, and completed. All processes begin in the not-yet-submitted state. My information comes from the standard input.

Each line below explained (respectively):

first line = CPUs in the system (1 to 4), the number of processes (1 to 25), and the quantum size (1 or larger).
second/third = the process ID (1 to 999), the process priority (1 to 10), 
the time of submission (non-negative),the total CPU time required (1 to 1000), 
the compute time before input/output is needed (1 to 100), 
and the input/output time for each compute-I/O cycle (1 to 1000).

```
Sample Input
1 2 10
1 1 0 10 5 10
2 2 3 10 5 10
```

The second and third lines are separated processes and there can be up to 25 processes. initially I was thinking just store each process into its own array so I could move that array from Queue to Queue with ease but creating 25 different arrays and then possibly not using them is very inefficient. Is there a more simple way store my "processes" so I can move them between the states (which is represented by the queues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a Process class that contains the state expressed on the second/third lines above.  Something like:

```
class Process {
    private int pid;
    private int priority;
    private int submissionTime;
    private int totalCpuTime;
}
```

And store instances of the class in a queue.  No reason not to make a queue for the waiting processes.  Then move the instances to other queues as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to create 4 tasks (one per CPU) which repeatedly..

- determine which task to perform next.
- perform that task
- repeat.

You can do this with a fixed size ExecutorService.

If you have an IO bound process, instead of a CPU bound process you can try to determine the optimal number of threads to use in advance and leave the number at that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is homework, and your are in a OO class, I would suggest you look at modelling processes as instances of a type you define.

For the other aspect of your question, you were talking about pre-allocating an array of size 25 because you don't know how many processes you have.

Look at Java's collection types. It has constructs like ArrayLists that provide fast index to object lookup, and doesn't force you to pre-allocate space.